# Importing functions that are in a different directory

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I am having trouble importing function from a different directory into my lib.rs in rust. I posted my code and file structure below.

However, when I put the get_users.rs into routes and add `pub mod get_users;` to `src/routes/mod.rs` the server spins up and the get users work.

File Structure

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── lib.rs
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── routes
│       ├── echo.rs
│       └── mod.rs
|       |__ users
|            |__ get_users.rs
|            |-- mod.rs      
├── static
│   └── abruzzo.png
└── tests
    └── basic_test.rs
```

Error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `users` in `routes`
  --> src\lib.rs:15:17
   |
15 |         routes::users::get_users::get_users
   |                 ^^^^^ could not find `users` in `routes`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `rocket-mongo` due to previous error
```

main.rs

```
use rocket_mongo::rocket_builder;

fn main() {
    crate::rocket_builder().launch();
}
```

lib.rs

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#![allow(unused_attributes)]

#[macro_use] use rocket::*;
use rocket_contrib::helmet::SpaceHelmet;

mod routes;

pub fn rocket_builder() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite().attach(SpaceHelmet::default())
    .mount("/", routes![
        routes::echo::echo_fn,
        routes::ping::ping_fn,
        routes::users::get_users::get_users
    ])
}
```

src/routes/users/get_users.rs

```
use rocket::*;

#[get("/users")]
pub fn get_users() -> String {
    "List of users".to_string()
}
```

src/routes/users/mod.rs

```
pub mod get_users;
```

Things I have tried:

- Adding `mod routes::users;` to `lib.rs`
- Adding `use routes::users:get_users;`

Edit: I dont know how to reply to comments but Jakub Dóka answered me by saying I needed to add `pub mod users;` in my src/routes/mod.rs file. Thank you so much Jakub!

Comment: Could you show the content of routes/mod.rs?

Comment: Do you have `pub mod users;` in `src/routes/mod.rs`?